# how to acces event in Mainpage.xaml to other xaml pages

Tags: silverlight

I have mainpage.xaml in that I created event as

```
Public Event ValueChanged()
```

I am raising the event on dropdown selectedindexchanged event as

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectionChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectionChanged
    RaiseEvent ValueChanged()
End Sub
```

I need to access this event in test.xaml page how I need to call the event..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass a reference of the MainPage instance to your TestPage by using a constructor

```
Public Sub New(mainPage As MainPage){
   // store reference and register event;
}
```

or add a property to your TestPage to set a reference to MainPage

```
Public Property MainPage() As MainPage
    Get
        Return m_MainPage
    End Get
    Set
        m_MainPage = Value
            // register event of MainPage
    End Set
End Property
Private m_MainPage As MainPage
```

Comment: After creating the property what I need to do .Actually I need to call one method where in I have to hide the silverlight control. When dropdown selectedchanged event is raised I need to raise the ValueChanged() upon have to access the event in test.xaml page and i have to call HideControl() method.

Comment: I am not able to access the event in testpage.xaml